# Filter bam with sambamba

Tags: sam, sambamba

I have a very large bam file and I want to filter it to keep only a handfull of positions as defined in a bed file. Can I do this with sambamba or do i need another tool?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible:

```
sambamba view --regions regions.bed --with-header --format=bam reads.bam  > filtered.bam
```

Comment: Hi @Pablo could you kindly edit your question inserting this as a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need [`bedtools`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), specifically [bedtools intersect](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html) command, not `sambamba`:

```
bedtools intersect -abam A.bam -b B.bed > A_in_N.bam
```